# 301 redirect 404 pages with regular expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches a string in url(/shop/test/) and redirect them to https://www.example.com/shop.
Example:

- https://www.example.com/shop/test/sometest
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/othertxt
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/newtest  etc.

to https://www.example.com/shop/

except

- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-light
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-medium
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-large

I need https://www.example.com/shop/test/(.*) to redirect to https://www.example.com/shop

EXCEPT

- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-light
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-medium
- https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-large

Comment: Is your list of exceptions a complete list or do these excepted elements follow a pattern?

Comment: all the excepted elements have **https://www.example.com/shop/test/obj-** in common, and there are only 3 urls of this type

Comment: Is `/shop/test/` a real directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule as your top rule in you site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop/test/(?!obj-)(.*)$ /shop/ [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```